FastAPI paralellization vs sequential run
I've been trying to follow this thread to better understand concurrency in fastAPI.  In particular, I've seen this comment:

In short, replace time.sleep() with await asyncio.sleep(), then you will get concurrency.

So, that's what I've tried to do:
import asyncio
import time

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/ping")
async def ping(request: Request):
    print("Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("bye")
    return {"ping": "pong!"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(
        "temp:app",
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port="8501",
        reload=True,
    )

The problem is that when I try to use the endpoint, it's still running sequentially:
Hello
bye
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50197 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Hello
bye
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50197 - "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 OK


Okay, answering to myself since I feel extremelty stupid and maybe it can help someone eventually. As it says in the other comment of that same post:

Chrome at least, blocks concurrent GET reuqests on the same URL (probably to get a chance to use the chached versin on the next one?) Testing with one Chrome in Incognito should work, with "def" as well as with "async def

So yeah, I've tried with one chrome in incognito and it worked

It is all explained in this answer (which was cited in your question).
